# Normalizing a business metric with respect to mix changes

Tags: regression, modeling, econometrics

I'm attempting to solve an interesting problem.  Company A's business transactions look like:  Customer1 purchased 3500 units of Product1 in 2019.  Customer2 purchased 250 units of Product2 and 150 units of Product3 in 2019, etc.

Company A keeps track of the amount of time it took to fulfill each order. For example, Customer1's order of Product1 took 3 seconds per unit to process, Customer2's order of Product2 took 5.1 seconds per unit, and Customer2's order of Product 3 took 6 seconds per unit.  Management wants to use the *overall* processing time per unit (averaged over all the units sent out in 2019) as a way of measuring efficiency in 2019.  I think this is incorrect.

Product2 is inherently different than Product3 (and every other product), so the average processing time for them will be different. If, in 2020, Company A gets a larger number of orders for slower products, then it would be unfair to say that Company A was less efficient in 2020 than it was in 2019.

Furthermore, Customer1 is inherently different than Customer2 (and every other customer), so the average processing time for Customer1's orders will be different than those for Customer2.  If, in 2020, Company A gets a larger number of orders from slower customers, then it would again be unfair to say that Company A was less efficient in 2020 than it was in 2019.

Going forward, I know the orders Company A has completed in the first half of 2020 (and their processing times), and I know the orders Company A is scheduled to fulfill in the second half of 2020. To be able to directly compare processing time per unit in 2019 to processing time per unit in 2020, I performed the following analysis:

Build a regression model on the transactions in 2019 to predict the processing time per unit of an order based on the Customer ID and the Product ID.  Then, feed the 2020 orders into the trained regression model to get an "expected" processing time for those orders, and compare the expected processing times spit out by the model with the actual processing times. One problem with my regression analysis is that there are 100 Customers, and 100 Products, so the matrix is singular and the coefficients are not unique.  It also doesn't take into account how efficiency is changing from month to month.

Is this a standard problem in Economics or Statistics?  My background is not in these fields.  I came across the idea of a Mix Analysis, but I think it only applies to one variable (e.g. Product Mix or Customer Mix, separately), and I'm not sure how to do it.  If anyone can confirm what I should do in this situation, that would be very helpful!